# Using ajax to implement timeout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timer

the code is like:

```
<?php
$base_arr=array("1","2","3","4");
?>
<table border=”1px” bordercolor="#F660AB" bgcolor="#FCDFFF"  width=30% height=50% align=center>
<?php
$k=0;
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)
        {
        ?>
    <td> <center><h5><a href="somehyper link"><?php echo $mat_ready[$i][$j]; ?> </h5></center></td>
    <?php
        }
        echo"</tr>";
}

?>
```

I want to use ajax to calculate time user take to click whn a 2x2 matrix is presented to him and also timeout if no response /click in 30 sec.

Comment: Why do you need AJAX for the timer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i want the time to get calculated in background and not on a a click..Let me know if there is another way